# FirebaseError: An internal error occurred

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am implementing kiosk project which is using firestore.

the kiosk is running very long time period(more than 48 hour).

But, sometimes my firestore onSnapShot listener makes erorrs with below message.

```
[Error message]
FirebaseError: An internal error occurred.
  at new FirestoreError(C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:348:28)
  at JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus(C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:4919:16)
  at JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange(C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:5417:44)
  at PersistentListenStream.onMessage(C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:13092:43)
  at ? (C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:13037:34)
  at PersistentListenStream.<anonymous>(C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:13013:47)
  at step(C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:133:27)
  at Object.next(C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:57)
  at ? (C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:107:75)
  at Promise(<anonymous>)
  at Object.__awaiter(C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:103:16)
  at ? (C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:13009:62)
  at ? (C:\release_pickUp_1210_v15\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:12485:20)
  at ? (<anonymous>)
```

And this is my codes.

```
componentDidMount() {
port.open(console.log('port is opend'));
if (TEST) {
  port.onRead(this.readFromPCBtest);
} else {
  port.onRead(this.readFromPCB);
}
this.unsubscribe = db.onceGetVM().onSnapshot(this.onErrorUpdate);
this.unsubscribeForOrders = db.onceGetOrders().onSnapshot(this.onOrdersUpdate);
this.unsubscribeForCleanings = db.onceGetCleanings().onSnapshot(this.onCleaningsUpdate);

for (let i = 0; i < cleaningList.length; i++) {
  unsubscribeForLatestOrders.push(db.onceGetLatestOrders(i).onSnapshot(this.onLatestOrdersUpdate));
  unsubscribeForLatestCleanings.push(db.onceGetLatestCleanings(i + 1).onSnapshot(this.onLatestCleaningsUpdate));
}

this.timer = setInterval(this.doClean, TIME_INTERVAL);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
port.close(console.log('port is closed'));
this.unsubscribe();
this.unsubscribeForOrders();
this.unsubscribeForCleanings();
this.unsubscribeForLatestOrders();
for (let i = 0; i < cleaningList.length; i++) {
  unsubscribeForLatestOrders[i]();
  unsubscribeForLatestCleanings[i]();
}
clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some internal problem in the firestore session.

I did add error handling function on "onSnapshot".

If the error occurs on "onSnapshot", It reconnects all of those listeners.

Until now(~3 weeks), There have been no problem to use firestore database.